# Motorola MC75 and Symbol - UnmarshalStructInfoFrom

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, compact-framework, symbols

I have this issue with a Motorola MC75 and the Symbol libraries.

So what I did is that I removed the "Symbol Managed Class Libraries" because I wanted to repro a bug that was happening on production.

But now that I installed back the "Symbol Managed Class Libraries" v 2.5 and copied back the file "symbol.all.arm.cab" to my mobile.

But when I try to load the Barcode Reader I get an exception that says:
"{Symbol.Exceptions.WrongMarshalSizeException: UnmarshalStructInfoFrom
   at Symbol.Marshaller.SymbolMarshal.UnmarshalStructInfoFrom(IntPtr pPtr, Int32 nOffset, Int32 nAllocated, Int32 nUsed)"

And the exact breakpoint where this occurs is when I call "reader.Actions.Enable()", reader is a "Symbol.Barcode.Reader()"

If you have any idea what is going on it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks, regards.

Comment: This appears to be a Motorola/Symbol-specific bug.  Have you checked with their support group?

Comment: I finally resolved this yesterday, I updated Symbol.dll and Symbol.Barcode.dll on my project and then deployed again to my mobile and it worked.

Comment: I have same issue, could you please help me with the updated dll location from where can i get these, as i'm unable to find any updated one.